# working of union

Tags: c

In union we know the memory used is maximum of the one occupied by its element but how on the same memory space different elements of the union can be stored ,are they not overwritten on the same memory space which cause to lose the prior element present there,i actually want to know the exact working of union while storing the different element..........

Comment: http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.7.2.1.html#1426 "The value of at most one of the members can be stored in a union object at any time."  http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.2.3.html  "If the member used to access the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called "type punning").  This might be a trap representation."

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be confused about what a `union` is.

These MSDN pages [here (c)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9zewe0d.aspx) and [here (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxy4b7b.aspx) go into more detail but basically a union is a mechanism where *the same memory address* can be referenced in different ways depending on the circumstances:

```
union sign   /* A definition and a declaration */
{
    int svar;
    unsigned uvar;
} number;
```

> This example defines a union variable
>   of type sign and declares a variable
>   named number that has two members:
>   svar, a signed integer, and uvar, an
>   unsigned integer. This declaration
>   enables the current value of number to
>   be stored as either a signed value or
>   an unsigned value. The tag that is
>   associated with this union type is
>   sign.

Answer (score 3):

You are right. Memory *is* overwritten since all elements share the same space. Take a look at this:

```
union foo{
    int i;
    char[4] carr;
};
```

Assuming integer is 4 bytes and char is 1 byte, if you modify the integer, all the four elements of the char array will be modified.

I would strongly suggest writing your own small code (with appropriate `printf`s) to understand the working of union. You will learn faster that way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a union does overlap members, so changing one can have the side-effect of changing another.  That's kind of the point.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be laboring under a misapprehension.

Assigning a new value of a different type *does* overwrite the existing data.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing more than a way to *view* or *interpret* the memory underlying the union structure. i.e. are these 4 bytes an integer, or a pointer, or contribute to a double etc ? (for example). Consequently, writing to your int will affect your pointer value, or your double.

And yes - writing a value in will overwrite the previous value - just like a normal struct (or anything else).

Comment: I think the key he was missing is that, since values overlap, overwriting one also affects others.

Answer (score 0):

**They are overwritten**, i.e. every time you assign one union member you change the other. That is actually the intent of the union in C - to be able to have different *typed* views on the *same bits in memory*. Classic example is checking the [endiannes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endiannes) of the platform at runtime (silly but illustrative):

```
union duo
{
    uint16_t short_;
    uint8_t  bytes[2];

} the_duo;

/* will assign either bytes[0] or bytes[1]
 * depending on the architecture */
the_duo.short_ = 1;

if ( the_duo.bytes[0] )
    printf( "little endian\n" );
else if ( the_duo.bytes[1] )
    printf( "big endian\n" );
else
    printf( "where am i?\n" );
```